# How to make and apply SVN patch?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I would like to make a SVN type patch file for `httpd.conf` so I can easily apply it to other hosts.

If I do

```
cd /root
diff -Naur /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf_original /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf > httpd.patch
cp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf_original /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
patch < httpd.patch
```

I get:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf_original    2012-04-26 13:36:08.331068438 +0200
|+++ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 2012-04-26 14:27:36.857075085 +0200
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

By default, `patch` ignores the directory portion of the target filename; it's just looking for "httpd.conf" in your current working directory.  If you want it to use the full path, you have to explicitly ask it to do so with the `-p` option:

`patch -p 0 < httpd.patch`

The number after `-p` is how many levels to remove from the filename path; `-p N`  strips off everything up to and including slash number N. The first slash is number 1, so `-p 0` means "don't strip anything".

In general, you might be better off not relying on having the full path in the patch file, though; the patch will be more generally useful if it works even for files in a different directory layout.  You can always cd into the directory containing the file before running patch (and use a full path to find the patch file itself, if needed, instead).

Answer (score 90):

Use **`svn patch`**.

Case 1: **using `/usr/bin/patch`**:

```
svn diff > $TMPDIR/mypatchfile.patch
cd myOtherCheckOut
patch -p0 < $TMPDIR/mypatchfile.patch
```

Applies your changes well if there are no added/deleted files through `svn add` or `svn delete`

Case 2: **using `svn patch`**:

```
svn diff > $TMPDIR/mypatchfile.patch
cd myOtherCheckOut
svn patch $TMPDIR/mypatchfile.patch
```

Tracks added and deleted files too.

Note that neither tracks `svn move`s and `rename`s

Comment: Make sure to disable any preconfigured diff tools if you have any, for the patch's sake (~/.subversion/config at diff_cmd)

Comment: Shouldn't svn patch use the same diff tool - and allow for the patch to be successful?

Comment: one-liner: `svn patch <(svn diff)`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using TortoiseSVN there is a easy to use interface to create and apply a patch.

**To create:**

Right click on folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Create patch

You will be prompted to select an output file

**To apply:**

Right click on folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Apply patch

You will be prompted with an interface to select the file(s) to apply the patches to, and merge if necassary.