# How do I output the difference between two specific revisions in Subversion?

Tags: svn, diff

I'm using Subversion via the Linux command line interface.

I want to see the difference between revision 11390 and 8979 of a specific file called `fSupplierModel.php` in my terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: Add here is how to apply it back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333712/how-to-make-and-apply-svn-patch

Answer (score 186, accepted):

See [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) in the manual:

```
svn diff -r 8979:11390 http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/fSupplierModel.php
```

Comment: If you want pretty output, install [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org) and add ` | colordiff` to the end of the above command to pipe everything through it.

Answer (score 67):

To compare entire revisions, it's simply:

`svn diff -r 8979:11390`

---

If you want to compare the last committed state against your currently saved working files, you can use convenience keywords:

`svn diff -r PREV:HEAD`

(Note, without anything specified afterwards, all files in the specified revisions are compared.)

---

You can compare a specific file if you add the file path afterwards:

`svn diff -r 8979:HEAD /path/to/my/file.php`

Comment: putting HEAD:PREV seemed to make more sense to me in the diff output, maybe will help others

Comment: @Fonix are you in the paradigm of "how does another commit differ from my current state"? If so, I agree. I usually think of chronological changes commits, so changes made in HEAD would have been the new/added changes from PREV, which is the paradigm I usually think in. There are cases and arguments to be made for either paradigm.

Comment: when you do git diff, it shows you what you added relative to a previous commit. PREV:HEAD makes more sense, but this is one of those things where some people prefer inverting the up and down controls for a joystick or trackpad. subjective idiosyncratic preference.

Comment: weirdly enough, i am one of those people who use an inverted mouse when playing FPS games :P

Comment: that would explain it :P